# MySQL statement to alter a table fails to work

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to change the child table by offering it a foreign key that references the parent over its id like this

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT (parentID int not null auto_increment primary key,...);
CREATE TABLE CHILD (childID int not null auto_increment primary key, parentID int not null,...);
```

Now the statement to fix the created table is

```
ALTER TABLE child CHANGE parentID parentID int not null foreign key references parent(childID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This fails to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: syntax error near "foreign key", I checked it in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: can you post the complete error string?

Answer (score 1):

Just say:

```
ALTER TABLE `CHILD`
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (parentId) REFERENCES `PARENT`(parentId) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

There's no need (afaik) to change the column type as it's already correct.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190273.aspx) regarding T-SQL-Syntax for ALTER. You probably want something like:

```
ALTER TABLE Child ALTER COLUMN...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line has the wrong column name reference for the foreign key, should reference parentID instead of childID.  You also have some syntax errors in there.

Try this instead:

```
ALTER TABLE child CHANGE parentID parentID int not null, 
add foreign key (parentID) references parent(parentID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```